# The points M and N and the circle k are given. Construct an equilateral triangle ABC inscribed in circle k such that |AM|=|BN|.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, constructive-mathematics

I chose an arbitrary length r and constructed two circles with centers in M ​​and N of radius r and marked their intersections with the given circle. Then I looked at the angle formed by the center of the given circle and those two intersections. I found the bisector of that angle and marked the intersection of the bisector and the circle with S. Finally, I found points A and B on the given circle such that triangles ASO and BS0 are equilateral, where O is the center of the given circle. However, I get that at such construction, |AM| is only approximately equal to |BN|. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are points $M$ and $N$ on the circle? Or, can they be inside the circle?

Comment: They can be anywhere. Since it's preferable to observe the most general case, I positioned them outside the circle.

Comment: I'll take that to mean that $M$ and $N$ can be anywhere subject to there being a solution. $A$ and $B$ must be on the circle, so if $M$ is very close to the circle and $N$ very far away then there won't be a solution, for example.

Comment: Sure there are cases in which there is no solution. So yeah, you're right.

Comment: Do you know what *constructive mathematics* is?

Comment: No I don't. Nor do I care honestly. But feel free to enlighten me on that matter if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Particular case where there is only two solutions:

As can be seen in figure, in this case center O of the circle and vertex A are on perpendicular bisector of MN . ABC is one solution and it's mirror about the diameter parallel with MN , triangle A'B'C' is the second one.

Answer (score 5):

Rotate point $N$ by $120°$ counterclockwise about the center $O$ of the circle, to $N'$ (this can be done by constructing three circles, as in figure below). If the perpendicular bisector of $MN'$ intersects the given circle at $A$, then $AM=AN'$. Finally, rotate $A$ by $120°$ clockwise about $O$, to $B$: we have then $AM=AN'=BN$ (by the congruence of triangles $OAN'$ and $OBN$), as requested.

Both intersections of the perpendicular bisector give a solution, and the initial rotation can also be clockwise: hence we can have up to four distinct solutions.

[image]

Comment: I was just about to ask you what "A′ must rotate counterclockwise by 120° to get B' " means, but I can see you changed it to ϕ and now it makes sense. Thank you for your input. I appreciate it. However, we aren't allowed to use algebraic methods solving this problem. Also, we aren't allowed calculators and we literally have to construct it using only a compass and rulers.

Comment: @kaykay I see. Is this taken from Euclidea?

Comment: No. It's one of the problems from my university exam.

Comment: I completely revised my answer, to give an euclidean construction.

Comment: Thank you so much!!